# How to enter text in a textfield by giving single space at the begining of the field?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

My text field is with rounded corners. When I am entering the text the characters are touching the left border which is not looking good how can I keep a single space at the beginning of the text field.

Comment: How did you get your text field to do rounded corners? If your text field is embedded in some other view or control, couldn't you just bump the text field to the right a bit?

Comment: I added textFeild.layer.cornerRadius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UIView *paddingView          = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
self.yourTextField.leftView             = paddingView;
self.yourTextField.leftViewMode         = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
textView.internalTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Its not a textView it is a textfield